# Visual Studio Code (Vscode) File Icon Issue: File Icons not showing in tab bar next to file opened. --See Details and Pictures Below

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

This is my first stack overflow post. I am learning web development so please bare with me.

I was watching a tutorial and notice the Youtuber had icons showing in the tab where you have open files to work on them. On mine they only appear on the side bar? Has anyone experience this problem and know how to fix it?

[My Vscode appearance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oLjS0.jpg)

[This guy on Youtube Vscode appearance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wQDGT.jpg)

[Another guy with the same thing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2De7i.jpg)

The settings are set right and I tried the settings with Seti (default) and Material Icon Theme (downloaded) and both have the same issue.

[My settings screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TlA0m.png)

[My extensions screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IjJxg.png)

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I am very dumb and I can't do simple searches apparently.

The toggle icon option was deselected in the settings apparently.
Once I selected it, the icons appeared and it was a simple fix.

[It was a setting option this whole time!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hDhom.png)